# Change boot order/Access BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, vmware-player, bootable-media

I have a virtual windows machine running in VMWare Player. In VMWare Workstation, there is an option [Power On to BIOS](https://www.isunshare.com/blog/how-to-set-vmware-boot-from-iso-image-file/), is there anything similar in **VMWare Player** to **access the BIOS** in order to change the boot order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following entry to the **vmx file** of the guest

```
bios.forceSetupOnce = "TRUE"
```

Power on the guest VM and it will boot into BIOS **once**. The entry is automatically removed from the vmx file. Readd it to the vmx file, if you want to boot into the BIOS again.